# Parse json object to string in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

this my code

```
app.get('/status',function ( req,res) {
        var data = {
            "error": 1,
            'data status': ""
        };
        connection.query("SELECT * from status", function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (rows.length != 0) {
            data = rows;
                console.log(data);
                res.json(data);
             } else {
                data["Data status"] = '0';
                res.json(data);
            }
        })
});
```

I had a problem I try to change the json object

```
[{"id_status":5,"pin_arduino":1,"status":0}]
```

I will eliminate be

`{"id_status":5,"pin_arduino":1,"status":0}`

Comment: Does `JSON.parse` not work?

Comment: Can you elaborate more what is that you want to acheive ?

Comment: yes i'am try JSON.parse, JSON.stringify not work @evolutionxbox

Comment: Why did you use stringify? Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I tried to remove the existing array format in json  @damitj07

Comment: use results element as a wrapper , {"results":[{"id_status":5,"pin_arduino":1,"status":0}]  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking for.

If you get this:

```
[{"id_status":5,"pin_arduino":1,"status":0}]
```

and you want this:

```
{"id_status":5,"pin_arduino":1,"status":0}
```

then instead of:

```
res.json(data);
```

use:

```
res.json(data[0]);
```

If you get this:

```
{"id_status":5,"pin_arduino":1,"status":0}
```

and you want this:

```
[{"id_status":5,"pin_arduino":1,"status":0}]
```

then instead of:

```
res.json(data);
```

use:

```
res.json([data]);
```

Also, looking at your examples, this:

```
data["Data status"] = '0';
```

should probably be:

```
data.status = 0;
```

or:

```
data[0].status = 0;
```

depending on how your data really looks like, which is not entirely clear from your question.

Note that you're not doing anything with JSON here. You just handle normal JS objects which get serialized to JSON automatically by Express when you use `res.json()` so there's no need to use `JSON.parse()` or `JSON.stringify()` at all, at least not in the code that you included in your question.